# Dynamically generate radio input for each element of jQuery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery slideshow plugin, and my 'slideshow' div naturally contains a handful of images. My objective is to add the ability for a user to rate the image, using either a radio or select widget.

Since I'm not using a sophisticated back end, the widget for each image must be generated on the fly in jQuery.

Each of the child elements of the slideshow div are naturally imgs, so it isn't clear to me how to append a form field to it using jQuery.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ (see the "creating elements on the fly" bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't mind some html to give you a better answer:

try:

```
    $('img').after('<input type="radio">'); //with realtion to your image
$('img').parent('div').after('<input type="radio">'); //with relation to the parent div
```

For starters...you could also try .appendTo, .add, .append...it depends on your container and how you want it displayed....Post some html for an exact answer. maybe even .before, .prepend, etc...again depending on what you really want to do...

I agree with karim, look those tags up to see which is best for you (i.e. do you want it in your div after your div, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give that a whirl.